# Removing the extension won't work

Tags: .htaccess

I've searched a whole lot to get this done.
I've found many solutions which people have claimed to be working.

But it's just not working for me. And I've got no idea why that is.

Below is my .htaccess as it is right now.
The first 4 lines of code are working correctly, the rest isn't.

Also, do I need to change the links in my navigation aswell?

***For the website click [here](http://dylanvanheugten.nl/).***

### CODE

```
Options Includes FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^dylanvanheugten.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  http://dylanvanheugten.nl/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php 

# Forces a trailing slash to be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone please help me fix my file?

Thanks in advance!

And one last thing, please explain what you are doing. ;-)

Comment: It's not removing the extenstion and also not leaving the trailing slash. (It's what the title says..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

will fail because you have a trailing slash. For example, if you request `/foo/bar/` expecting to get served the contents at `/foo/bar.php`, the trailing slash would make this condition check that `/foo/bar/.php` exists as a file, which doesn't.

You need to tailor your check to ignore the trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
```

The other thing you are missing is an external redirect for requests made for php files:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /([^/]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! But now my style seems to be missing.. Any idea how I can fix this?